# Mapbox IOS set initial region / set userLocation as initial location

Tags: swiftui, mapbox, mapbox-ios

Issue:
Whenever I open the MGLMapView, the first shown coordinate is the 0,0 Coordinate somewhere around africa, but I would like to have it set to the users initial **region** (e.g. USA/Germany...) by default. This is the default behavior in MapKit. Additionally I also can't find a way to set the initial (I really mean the first rendering) **location/coordinate** to the user-location, **without** animating to it form the 0,0 coordinate. I tried the following code in a SwiftUI workaround, which shouldn't affect the behavior:

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MGLMapView {
    let mapView = MGLMapView()
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    mapView.setZoomLevel(13, animated: false)
    mapView.setUserTrackingMode(.followWithHeading, animated: false) {}
    return mapView
}
```

Comment: Are u using SwiftUI or UIKit?

Comment: There are methods in the MapView delegate that will allow you to do what you need.

Comment: Yes I am using SwiftUI. Which method do you exactly mean? I can't find one setting it before first render... Please be so kind and show me :)

Comment: The delegate method `mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap` will let you set the centre coordinate before the mapView is actually displayed. I use it all the time, though the method name might be a little misleading. I think the 'loading' refers to the MGLMapView being initialised, rather than presented to the user.

Comment: Oh, I tried `mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap` but what should I place in there? It doesnt places my rough region at all. Also when I set the `userTrackingMode` in there it also just scrolls to the current position through whole africa ^^. I could call the `setCenter()` manually from my own `LocationManager()` and set `userTrackingMode` after that, but is this the only possible way? Thanks for helping btw!!